# step by step to build my own robot

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-groovy, collada-urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am a beginner user with ROS and I read some tutorials about it specially (catkin,urdf,rviz, gazebo,roscpp).

My question is: I need steps (step by step) of how to build my own robot? as till now I am NOT knowing how to start to build my own robot, Please becareful with that I read urdf,rviz,gazebo,groovy tutorials

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and ROS Groovy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66980/step-by-step-to-build-my-own-robot/) by [ahmed.shamroukh](https://answers.ros.org/users/5253/ahmed.shamroukh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-07-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-07-10**:
Consider having a look at Robotic Open Platform, http://www.roboticopenplatform.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS is probably not a good solution to your problem, as it is not designed to help you build a robot, it will however help you use one, provided that you have or add support for ROS to it.

There are tons of blogs and resources all across the internet that talk about making robots, from the simple wheeled line follower to the full-fledged humanoid robot. Google *how to make a robot* and pick your choice.

A few pieces of advice:

- if you want to use ROS on it, I suggest you go for an x86 architecture, with support for Ubuntu Linux, as it will provide you with optimum ROS compatibility
- you can start with simulation only, so that you get familiar with algorithms and methods, if not already done, I suggest you follow the Gazebo tutorials on how to make a small robot [like this one](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.5/build_robot/mobile_base), how to write plugins, and ROS nodes
- please try to break down your problem before submitting it to the community. If you have a specific issue with a piece of software, a sensor or actuator, then you are likely to receive an answer if one exists. Questions such as *how to build a robot* are way less likely to receive an answer

**Short answer**: google is your friend, ROS answers is not really the good place for your question

---

Originally posted by [po1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4425/po1/) with karma: 411 on 2013-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahmed.shamroukh](https://answers.ros.org/users/5253/ahmed.shamroukh/) on 2013-07-15**:
NO no, I mean I have the mechanical design already done, and I need to control it using ROS, So I need the steps to do this

**Comment by [VEGETA](https://answers.ros.org/users/26893/vegeta/) on 2016-07-01**:
can you send me pics or info about ur design and how u did it? TY

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did not mean that what is the steps (Software steps) to create my own robot using ROS.
I do not mean how to create robot at general, I mean What should I learn first in ROS then second then third ...... to create my own designed robot at the final

---

Originally posted by [ahmed.shamroukh](https://answers.ros.org/users/5253/ahmed.shamroukh/) with karma: 1 on 2013-07-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [po1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4425/po1/) on 2013-07-15**:
Again, it is a mistake to believe that ROS will help you design a robot. It can guide your choice of hardware because of its compatibility list, but it will not, for example, replace a CAD tool such as Solidworks.